# How to create multiple range from a list of numbers in R?

Tags: r, range

If i have a list of numbers:

```
> list1
 [1]   58659   59837 2603675 2607619 2607631 2608098 2608106 2608975 2608978 2609613
 [11] 2609635 2610225 2610235 2610408 2610453 2610782 2610799 2611212 2611232 2611642
 [21] 2611646 2611825 2611828 2612151 2612154 2612741 2612943 2614220 2614222 2614941
 [31] 2615008 2616276 2616304 2617656
```

Is there a function that creates two list based on the threshold (For example `100000`) i provide and results in

```
[1] 58659 59837 2603675 2617656
```

Another simpler example

```
>list2
[1] 1 2 3 4 11 12 13 14
```

with a threshold of 2, it will give out

[1] 1 4 11 14

Comment: To be clear: you're trying to find the minimal number of ranges such that each range is no larger than some threshold, and all values fall within one of the ranges?

Comment: That's what your first example suggests, but in your second example you give a threshold of two and yet both of the ranges (1-4 and 11-14) are of width 3

Comment: If the difference between two numbers are less than 2, they will be one range, if not on a different range. Same for the first example. 

I am looking for multiple ranges and different ranges are triggered based on the threshold, and withing range difference is always smaller than threshold. 

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: To be clear: you mean that two *consecutive* values within the threshold will be in the same range? Because in your second example, values 1 and 4 are *3* apart (more than the threshold) but you put them in the same range.

Comment: yes, consecutive values are correct. So,even if one value is under the threshold, it should be in one range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those ranges with the following trick (where `list2` is your vector and `2` your threshold):

```
tapply(list2, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(list2) > 2)), range)
```

It might look quite arcane, but here's a walkthrough. You start with the useful `diff` function to find consecutive differences:

```
list2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14)
diff(list2)
# 1 1 1 7 1 1 1
```

Then if you check which items are greater than your threshold, you find out where the breaks (starts of new groups) are:

```
diff(list2) > 2
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Notice that it is one shorter than your original list (because the number of consecutive differences is n - 1). To fix this, append a TRUE to the start (because the first element is always the start of a new group):

```
c(TRUE, diff(list2) > 2)
# [1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But that just tells you where the breaks are, not what each element's group is. But the cumulative sum will tell you that (since sum treats TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0):

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(list2) > 2))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

Now we're getting somewhere! `tapply` is a useful function that applies a function over a vector based on groups defined by another vector, like these 1 and 2 groups we have here. We want to apply the `range` function to learn the range (min and max) within each group:

```
result = tapply(list2, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(list2) > 2)), range)
result[[1]]
# 1 4
result[[2]]
# 11 14
```

Note that this is a list, which in my opinion is more useful than a concatenated vector like `1 4 11 14`. But just in case you do want it in that format, you can do:

```
do.call(c, result)
```

to combine it together into a single vector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `diff` to find out the space between each consecutive value, and then extract the values to the left and right of that space. Here is a sample function:

```
f<-function(x,thresh){
  pos<-which(diff(x)>thresh)
  x[unique(c(1,pos,pos+1,length(x)))]
}

x<-unname(unlist(read.table(textConnection('58659   59837 2603675 2607619 2607631 2608098 2608106 2608975 2608978 2609613 2609635 2610225 2610235 2610408 2610453 2610782 2610799 2611212 2611232 2611642 2611646 2611825 2611828 2612151 2612154 2612741 2612943 2614220 2614222 2614941 2615008 2616276 2616304 2617656'))))
f(x,10000)
# [1]   58659   59837 2603675 2617656
x<-c(1:4,11:14)
f(x,2)
# [1]  1  4 11 14
```